# Particular property of a function that admits a Taylor expansion and $f(2/3)=3/2$

Tags: taylor-expansion, irrational-numbers

I'm trying to prove this original statement :

> *Let suppose that $f$ is a function that admits a Taylor expansion such that*  $$ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \
> > f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nx^n $$
>   *with $a_n \in \left\{0,1\right\}$ and that* $$f\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{3}{2}$$
>
> *Prove that $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is irrational.*

My idea was to prove it by supposing the existence of two integers $p$ and $q$ with $p \wedge q=1$ such that
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{p}{q}
$$
and to show that there is a contradiction.
With the hypothesis i only know that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n=\frac{3}{2}
$$
Maybe I could use that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{a_n}{3^n}=\frac{3}{2}f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
and to use Cauchy's product but it seems not the right way. Any help ?

Comment: First prove that the condition on $f$ implies that $a_n=1$ for infinitely many $n$. Then prove that the sequence $a_0,a_1,\dots$ can't be eventually periodic (this may be the hard part – I haven't actually tried it). Then conclude that $f(1/2)$ is irrational as its binary expansion is nonterminating and not eventually periodic.

Comment: Okay, but how can I link the fact that $f(2/3)=3/2$ and that $a_n$ can't be periodic ?

Comment: If the $a_n$ are eventually periodic, then the series is something with denominator a power of 3 plus a geometric series, with common ratio a power of $2/3$. Maybe you can use that. Worth a try.

Comment: I think I've found, thank you

Comment: Good! Let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: I just saw that there is a quack, i've shown that if $a_n$ was periodic, then $f(1/2)$ was rationnal. However, it does not prove tht $a_n$ is not periodic,  only if we suppose already the result ...

Comment: This appears to be 2017 Putnam problem B3, come up again at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736497/putnam-competition-2017-problem-b3